# iphone - expandible center button in tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface

How does one go about implementing this? i've figured out how to implement the custom center button but not the part where you click the button and it gets expanded with more options.

[image: First image, custom centered button]

---

[image: Custom centered button expanded]

Answer (score 0):

> How does one go about implementing this?

It's a custom view. The bottom bar there is probably not a tab bar, and maybe not even a tool bar -- it may be a custom view as well. When you tap on the center view, it expands to reveal additional content.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two views here.

The **first one** is the 'tabbar'

The **second one** is the centered rounded button

The second view is added above the first one and is actually bigger than the screen.

Now, when the user clicks on the arrow, an animation might be executed to show the whole view.